# When request the resources of HTML page will open new TCP connections?

Tags: http, tcp, httprequest

We know when request a web page, there will open a TCP connection, request the html page.

there is an example:
[image]

Suppose, there open the TCP connection:

```
192.168.1.2.54587   ---   104.17.23.75.443 (cloudflare)
```

we know, in the main HTML page, there are many js files, css files and images embed in it.
when request those resources, will open new TCP connections? or just use the existing connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the actual application protocol used and its configuration. With HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 (which is not even TCP, i.e. it uses UDP) the same underlying connection will be used as long as the requested resource is on the same server.

With HTTP/1 a new TCP connection will be created or an existing one reused, depending if an existing connection can be used at all (HTTP keep-alive), is idle and how many TCP connections are already used to the target. Details are browser specific too.